# Do electrons build up at the entrance of a resistor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors

There is a voltage drop between the start and end point of a resistor. How does it achieve this difference in potential? For there to be a difference in potential there must be difference in charges. So do electrons build up at the entrance which in turn creates a difference in potential?

Comment: Yes.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Extremely small excess of electrons will build up at the entrance, but actually along the entire wire from battery to resistor. It is _not_ just at the entrance surface of the resistor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Voltage drop = more electrons on one side of resistor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143300/)