# Why is the electric field the strongest inside the resistors?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, potential-energy, voltage

My understanding is that current is constant throughout the circuit. So it means that in the areas with high resistivity or small cross-sectional area the drift speed on electrons is the highest. Draft speed is proportional to the strength of the electric field, so the electric field is the strongest in the areas with high resistance. I'm confused as to what causes the strong electric field inside the resistor. Is it some kind of excess charge on the ends of the resistors?
Another aspect that confuses me is why is the circuits consisting of just wires (no resistors), the potential decreases gradually from positive to negative terminal, but in the circuits with resistors the potential drops suddenly at the resistor. Why is that and why in the circuits with resistors potential doesn't decrease at all in the segments with low resistance?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused as to what causes the strong electric field inside the resistor. Is it some kind of excess charge on the ends of the resistors?

Yes, the higher electric field in a resistive segment must be accompanied by net positive charge where current enters the resistor, and net negative charge where it exits, [see here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143300/voltage-drop-more-electrons-on-one-side-of-resistor). Electrons pile up where they encounter high resistance. The high field in the resistive segment can be understood as the accumulated electrons pushing the electrons in the resistor through with enough force to ensure there is no further piling-up.

> Another aspect that confuses me is why is the circuits consisting of just wires (no resistors), the potential decreases gradually from positive to negative terminal, but in the circuits with resistors the potential drops suddenly at the resistor. Why is that and why in the circuits with resistors potential doesn't decrease at all in the segments with low resistance?

Because of how potential is defined, the rate of potential drop as you go along the circuit is proportional to the E-field. So the reasoning is the same as above: a small E-field is needed to push electrons through a segment with low resistance, resulting in a small potential drop. There *is* potential drop along segments with low resistance, it's just that in practice it is often negligible compared to the voltage drops in resistive segments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a couple of follow-up questions: